# TukeyHSD function or glht for post-hoc test after ANCOVA

Tags: r, linear-regression, posthoc, tukey, ancova

I'm currently performing an ANCOVA in R testing the difference in the levels of fungi depending on the types of fungi while correcting for a difference in the age of the fungi (days).

```
model <- aov(fungi_level ~ fungi_types + days, data = fungi_data)
Anova(model, type = "III")
```

Here, I find a significant difference between the different fungi types and want to perform post-hoc testing. As far as I can see there are (at least) two different ways to perform TukeyHSD:

```
TukeyHSD(model, which = 'fungi_types')
```

Which gives an error: "... non-factors ignored: days"

or

```
PostHoc <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(fungi_types = "Tukey"))
```

**Does anyone know the difference between the two different tests?** It seems that the glht is more restrictive when looking at the p-values.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two options to get the posthoc test Tukey: Use a package called 1. `mcp` or 2. `Rcmdr`. Tukey is the default option in the one-way ANOVA command.

Comment: Details: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373045/which-is-right-to-perform-a-tukey-post-hoc-in-r>